# multiple cron job command not working

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cron

I tried to use cron tab for the two test program as follows to see both of them works.

```
43 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py
43 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/VillaHouseForSale.py
```

**Problems**

1. The first one runs but the second one doesnt. I dont know why. can
   anyone correct it?
2. If i run both of the cron tabs at the same
   time, will they run concurrently?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you checked if both files have the same privileges?

Comment: what kind of priviliges?

Comment: What do you get if you do `-ls -l /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py` and the same for the other file?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 ahmed ahmed 8927 Mar 25 16:07 /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 ahmed ahmed 8920 Mar 25 16:15 /home/ahmed/Desktop/VillaHouseForSale.py

Comment: NOW what should i do?

Comment: As both files have the same properties, it looks like the cron expression is fine. Hence, there might be some problem in your code. Check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info for common errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do both scripts run correctly from the commandline?

Making both scripts executable may help

```
chmod +x /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py
chmod +x /home/ahmed/Desktop/VillaHouseForSale.py
```

Have you tried running them on the same line like one of these?

```
43 12 * * * /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py & /home/ahmed/Desktop/VillaHouseForSale.py
43 12 * * * /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py && /home/ahmed/Desktop/VillaHouseForSale.py
43 12 * * * /home/ahmed/Desktop/AppForSale.py ; /home/ahmed/Desktop/VillaHouseForSale.py
```

Have you tried creating and then running a script that executes both files?
So that you would have

```
43 12 * * * ScriptThatRunsBothFiles.sh
```